# How to Assign to PageData and UrlData in a Custom Route Handler?

Tags: asp.net, razor, url-routing, asp.net-webpages

How do you assign to the UrlData and PageData properties of WebPage or WebPageBase? I'm trying to write a custom route handler and it says that the properties are read-only. This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.WebPages;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CustomRazorRouteHandler
/// </summary>
public class CustomRazorRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public string VirtualPath { get; set; }

    public CustomRazorRouteHandler(string virtualPath)
    {
        this.VirtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var page = WebPage.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath);
        foreach (var item in requestContext.RouteData.Values)
        {
            page.PageData[item.Key] = item.Value;       // Null reference exception
            page.UrlData.Add(item.Value.ToString());    // Read-only error
        }

        var handler = WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath);
        return handler;
    }
}
```

The web app is meant for Medium Trust, so Reflection is not really an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is no way to assign PageData and UrlData without reflection because the lists are marked as read-only. My work around is to create a couple of helpers that store the url peices in the HttpContext and read them back out.